# BookshelfJS - 'withRelated' through relational table returns empty results

Tags: orm, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I've been trying to structure the relations in my database for more efficient querying and joins but after following the guides for *'.belongsToMany'*, *'.through'* and *'.belongsTo'* I'm now getting empty results.

I've got a **Sound** model and a **Keyword** model which I want to model with a many-to-many relationship (each Sound can have multiple Keywords, and each Keyword can be related to multiple sounds). Based on the documentation '.belongsToMany' would be the relation to use here.

I've set up my models as follows, using a 'sound_keyword' relational table/**SoundKeyword** relational model (where each entry has it's own unique *'id'*, a *'soundID'*, and a *'keywordID'*):

```
var Sound = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'sounds',
  keywords: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany(Keyword, 'sound_keyword', 'id', 'id').through(SoundKeyword, 'id', 'soundID');
  },
});

var Keyword = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'keywords',
  sounds: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany(Sound, 'sound_keyword', 'id', 'id').through(SoundKeyword, 'id', 'keywordID');
  }
});
```

where:

```
var SoundKeyword = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'sound_keyword',
    sound: function () {
        return this.belongsTo(Sound, 'soundID');
    },
    keyword: function () {
        return this.belongsTo(Keyword, 'keywordID');
    }
});
```

From what I've read in the docs and the BookshelfJS GitHub page the above seems to be correct. Despite this when I run ***the following query*** I'm getting an empty result set (the Sound in question is related to 3 Keywords in the DB):

```
var results = await Sound
    .where('id', soundID)
    .fetch({
        withRelated: ['keywords']
    })
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result.related('keywords')));
    })
```

Where am I going wrong with this? Are the relationships not set up correctly (Possibly wrong foreign keys?)? Am I fetching related models incorrectly?

Happy to provide the Knex setup as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATED EDIT:**

I had been using the [Model-Registry Plugin](https://github.com/bookshelf/bookshelf/wiki/Plugin:-Model-Registry) from the start and had forgotten about it. As it turns out, while the below syntax is correct, it prefers syntax similar to the following (i.e. lowercase 'model', dropping the '.extends' and putting model names in quotes):

```
var Sound = bookshelf.model('Sound',{
  tableName: 'sounds',
  keywords: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany('Keyword', 'sound_keyword', 'soundID', 'keywordID');
  },
});

var Keyword = bookshelf.model('Keyword',{
  tableName: 'keywords',
  sounds: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany('Sound', 'sound_keyword', 'keywordID', 'soundID');
  }
});
```

### Hope this can be of help to others.

Seems like removing the '.through' relation and changing the IDs in the '.belongsToMany' call did the trick (as below), though I'm not entirely sure why (the docs seem to imply *belongsToMany* and .*through* work well together - possibly redundant?)

```
var Sound = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'sounds',
keywords: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany(Keyword, 'sound_keyword', 'soundID', 'keywordID');
  },
});

var Keyword = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'keywords',
  sounds: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany(Sound, 'sound_keyword', 'keywordID', 'soundID');
  }
});
```

I did try my original code with *soundID* and *keywordId* instead of '*id*' (as below), but without the *.through* relation and that gave the same empty results.